# Can Heat Transfer occur between two bodies with the same temperature but different states only through Latent Heat Transfer?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-transition

I understand that temperature difference is the driving force for heat transfer but I have been wondering whether there would be any heat transfer, let's say if steam at 100 degree Celsius and water at 100 degree Celsius are passed through the two sides of a Heat Exchanger.

Comment: Don't see how there could be heat transfer. If the only communication they have with each other is through a heat exchanger, then the only information that they can communicate to each other is that they're both at 100 ˚C. If that's the case then how can heat transfer in either direction occur? Is there some particular perspective from which you're looking at this problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Samuel, It has provided me with more clarity on this. I am not looking at this from any specific perspective, rather it just popped up on my mind on whether latent heat can be passed on without a delta T and I haven't been able to convince myself. Just curious, Is temperature difference a sole driving force for heat transfer in situations like these, in heat exchangers, especially shell and tube ones?
P.S: I am new here, I couldn't figure out a way to upvote your comment.

Comment: According to my understanding of equilibrium thermodynamics, temperature is the sole driving force for heat transfer in the situation you described. Perhaps there may be some deep subtleties that arise in the case of very small bodies when statistical fluctuations become important so that the distinction between water at 100 ˚C and steam at 100 ˚C becomes significant, but that's delving deeper into statistical mechanics than my knowledge goes.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect, Pieter. I understood the entropy discussion but the surface tension effects mentioned by you overwhelmed me a bit, and if I understood correctly, for minimal surface area, phase change wouldn't take place? Sorry if this is too much to ask, but in simpleton terms, will there be heat transfer just due to entropy differences, specific to this case. 
@SamuelWeir Would love to hear your insights on this too, if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible if the states are somehow not reversible(might not be the proper word for that). For example if you have water and air at ambient temperature then water will evaporate as long as the air isnt saturated.

Comment: I think I disagree with that statement. There is evaporation, but no heat transfer to the surroundings in this case. I will post a detailed answer to clarify

Comment: I spoke a bit too fast. There is actually a transfer in this situation, but not between two bodies at the same temperature, like OP was asking. Cf my answer :)

Comment: What you're describing isn't heat transfer. Heat transfer requires a gradient in the thermodynamic temperature. The original poster specified a boundary between the two systems to rule out other energy-transfer mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the academical answer to your question is no. There is probably a way to justify properly with the second law of thermodynamics, I will think about it and come back later if I find it.

However, in practise, you might find processe that very much "look like it", like in the example that Manu was giving.

For now, I would like to come back on it, because I think it is a good illustration. Actually, I half-afgree with his point, but I want to stress that even in this case, it will always be a temperature difference that drives the heat flow.

Let us consider liquid water initally at ambient temperature T in an unsaturated atmopshere. If this atmosphere is unsaturated, our system is not in equilibrium. Indeed, even if the water is way below 100 degrees C, it is still above its boiling point **at the partial pressure in water contained in the atmosphere**.

This means that the water will indeed spontaneously evaporate. So it does need some heat. But actually, it can take it... from itself ! We are in a **superheated state** (water below its boiling point in the operating conditions), which means that the water can cool down : it takes its own temperature energy to use it as latent heat ! My point is that this evaporation does not need any transfer from outside : everything could happen adiabatically (like the freezing of a supercooled liquid in isolated conditions, but reversed). The decrease in temperature of the water provide its own necessary energy for evaporation.

This being said, of course, the water is in contact with the air, and we can not provide adiabatic conditions. So indeed, as the water starts to evaporate by its own, it decreases a bit in temperature, so it starts pumping heat from the atmosphere thanks to this newly created dT.

In the end, the process does take heat from the air, and that helps sutain the evaporation. But this process still occurs thanks to temperature gradient. **There is no transfer between phases at the same temperature in this situation** (it is just that the process naturally causes gradient to appear)

Comment: Not sure that the evaporation of water in air is the right example. Take a closed system of water in a vacuum bottle. The water evaporates only as long as the saturation with the gasious water is reached. From the very beginning of this process the gas has to be considered at with 0 Kelvin and than increases to the temperature of the water (which loses some temperature).

Comment: The choice of this process was to adress Manu's answer :)

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of thermodynamics, heat is defined as energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Period. If there is no temperature difference, there is no energy transfer in the form of heat.

Phase changes may or may not involve heat transfer. For example, water may evaporate in air even though the water and air are at the same temperature. This is a surface phenomenon due to some water molecules at the surface have higher than the average bulk kinetic energy of the liquid allowing them to escape.

However, when they do it is because the there is a temperature difference between the substance undergoing the phase change and something else.   The heat transfer causes a phase change in the substance without changing the temperature of the substance. This heat is referred to as “latent (hidden) heat” because the heat doesn’t increase the temperature of the substance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: From a practical perspective (i.e., industrial experience), the answer is "no".

Comment: @DavidWhite Agree. By "thermodynamics perspective" I was referring to the proper definition of heat, only because, as you would probably agree, the term "heat" is so often misused.

Comment: Bob, I agree.  When I taught thermodynamics at the high school level, I cautioned my students that the English language would get in their way.  "Heat" is not hot ... it's a transfer of energy that can exist at any temperature due to a temperature difference.  The misconception is so ingrained in us that it is difficult to appreciate the full meaning of my previous statement.